# django with ssl redirect and ajax post gives a 301 error

Tags: ajax, django, ssl

I am using [this django snippet [1]](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/) to redirect to my https website. I know it does not work with POST requests so I did not add the `{'SSL': True }` in the all the url POST requests in my `urls.py`. However I always get a 301 error (in my access logs), although the view does what it is asked to do.

The view is 'called' by an ajax request and returns a json object.

```
def confirm(request, username):
    if username == request.user.username:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            response_dict = {
                'status': True,
                'added_total': count,
                'username': username,
                'message': message
            }
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/fx/%s?page=%s' % (username, '1'))
    else:
        raise Http404(u'Not a valid user')
```

I also tried to add the `{'SSL': True}` argument but I still get the 301 error.

for ajax post requests I also use this snippet:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function (xhr, settings) {
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie != "") {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is my action from `urls.py` 
`url(r'^confirm/(\w+)/$', confirm),`

[1] http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/85/

Comment: Which URL do you POST to? A POST to `/foo` might be 301 to `/foo/` and thus POST fails.